# SQL Server Indexing Ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, database-performance

I have a table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VideoRecipient](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IssueId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [NotifiedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ReceivedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ReadDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [AcknowledgedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DeletedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_VideoRecipient] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
))
```

I then create an index as below

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UX_VideoRecipient_UserId_IssueId_CreatedDateTime ON [dbo].VideoRecipient ([UserId], [IssueId], [CreatedDateTime]) INCLUDE ([ReadDateTime], [ReceivedDateTime], [AcknowledgedDateTime], [NotifiedDateTime])
```

When I make a query to get the record via the **UserId**, it uses the index and it uses an index seek which is what I want.
If I then make a query to get the records by the **IssueId**, it does an index scan which is slower. Other than create another index and specify the **IssueId** as the first column to index on, is there a way to make the index a seek instead of a scan?

Specifying the first column to index would seem to be more important than I originally thought!

Comment: column order is incredibly important. https://bertwagner.com/2018/09/04/does-the-order-of-index-columns-matter/

Comment: Imagine you have a phone book (if you know of such things) that lists everyone's names in `surname, first name` order. Use that book to find everyone with a first name of `John`. How easy does the book make this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index essentially creates another version of the table that only includes the columns you've mentioned. It is then sorted in the exact order in which you indicate (in your example it's in the order of UserId->IssueId->CreatedDateTime). Since the IssueId column in your index is second it means that the values will not be in order if that is the main value you're searching on. Because of this, SQL has to perform a 'scan' of all rows in the index to find the item(s) you're searching for.

If you intend to search on only IssueId then you'll need to adjust your index. If you plan to have multiple queries that search on the different values then you'll need different indexes.

But please keep in mind that adding indexes to a table will slow down inserts and updates slightly since the indexes need to be updated at the same time before the change is committed. Because of this you'll want to make sure that if you're creating an index it is because you need it as opposed to "just in case".

Comment: Yes thanks so I was wondering if I was missing anything but seems not. Yes the worry of creating too many indexes. cheers for the confirmation

Answer (score 1):

The index created on `([UserId], [IssueId], [CreatedDateTime])` is useful only when your query filter on

- UserId
- UserId, IssueId
- UserId, CreatedDateTime
- UserId, IssueId, CreatedDateTime

If you just search on `UserId` you should not add other `fields` as `key fields`.

You cannot use this index to search on `IssueId` or `CreatedDateTime` as they are not the **most left key field** of the `index`.

You should think twice before adding an `index` similar to that you created: your `index` has **all the columns** of original `table`, this means you just **duplicated** it. But if you look at the `size` of your `nonclustered index` you'll find that it is **even greater** than your original `table` size. It may be not a problem for small size tables but it's really a problem for large tables.

If most of your queries searches on `UserId` you may think about refactoring your `clustered index`: it should be defind on the column used for most of your seeks, and PK can be defined as `nonclustered`.

Another problem with the `index` that completely duplicates your `table` is that **any update of any field** with cause your `index` to be updated and it will slow down your data modifications.